# No matching function to (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I'm trying to find a data from the keyboard in a vector (where the elements are from structure). And i've got crazy with this error message. Here are my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    string code;
    string name;
    string brand;
    int price;
};

vector<item> vstr;

int main(){

   vstr.push_back({"NK-001", "Nikon D3100", "Nikon", 200});
   vstr.push_back({"NK-002", "Nikon D3200", "Nikon", 400});
   vstr.push_back({"NK-003", "Nikon D3300", "Nikon", 350});

   string keywd = "NK-001";
   auto f = find(begin(vstr), end(vstr), keywd);

   if(f!= end(vstr)){
       cout << "Data Found";
   }
   else {
       cout << "Data Not Found";
   }
}
```

Any suggestions and helps are welcome. Thanks in advance :)

## EDIT

So here's the error message :

> 

```
D:\Tugas Kuliah\Algoritma dan Pemrograman\Tugas Kelompok>g++ -std=c++11 coba.cpp -o coba
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from coba.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<item*, std::vector<item> >; _Value = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<item*, std::vector<item> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<item*, std::vector<item> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:3792:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<item*, std::vector<item> >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
coba.cpp:24:47:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'item' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

Comment: Not related to your actual problem (which one BTW?), but `using namespace std;` rarely is a good idea.

Comment: Once asking about compilation errors - copy paste entire message, without paraphrasing, into the question itself.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry and thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole thing is that you need to switch from `std::find` to `std::find_if`:

```
const auto it = std::find_if(std::cbegin(vstr), std::cend(vstr),
    [&keywd](const auto& item) {
        return item.code == keywd;
});
```

as you cannot compare `item` and `std::string` directly.

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/rsVCDB)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solves my problem.
P.S : I'm using -std=c++14 to make the compiling process work

Comment: @DhimasYoga It might work with C++11 as well if you change the lambda from `[&keywd](const auto& item)` to something like `[&keywd](const item& o)`... But the main thing is to use `std::find_if`, of course)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain what `[&keywd](const auto& item]` do? I'm curious on how it works

Comment: @DhimasYoga `&keywd` is capturing `keywd` by reference so it is accessible inside lambda, `const auto& item` is a generalized lambda syntax so the real type of the object is deduced by the compiler and you do need to specify it as `item` explicitly.

Comment: So, the `&keywd` is a pointer that capture the keywd value and save it into an address? Then the `const auto& item` will find the value from item that is match with the `&keywd`? I think it's work like that from what i can understand. Thank you very much for your explanation! :)